# error trying to access form elements in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I trying to rewrite a project from python to c++.
I imported the form into my project, but when accessing it, a runtime error occurs (see below)
I can access the methods of the form, but when executed, it gives an error

[image]
below is all the code involved

plaindict.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_plaindict.h"

namespace Ui {
class PlainDict;
}

class PlainDict : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PlainDict(QDialog *parent = nullptr);
    ~PlainDict();

private:
    Ui::PlainDict *ui;
};
```

plaindict.cpp

```
#include "plaindict.h"
#include "ui_plaindict.h"
PlainDict::PlainDict(QDialog *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PlainDict)
{
    ui->inputLine->setText("regetrg");

    ui->setupUi(this);
}
PlainDict::~PlainDict()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "plaindict.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PlainDict w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = PlainDict
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        plaindict.cpp \
    modelfororiginal.cpp

HEADERS += \
        plaindict.h \
    modelfororiginal.h\


FORMS += \
        plaindict.ui
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: you can't access ui elements before `ui->setupUi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ui->inputLine->setText("regetrg");
ui->setupUi(this);
```

Here you access `inputLine` before it is initialized by that `setupUi` call.

To fix, switch order of these lines.